# Python *self.args, **self.kwargs are causing error inside class

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, args

I've been trying to make a simple tool to help make independent requests to use scrapy more fluently in my mind but I've been running into a error and I do not know how to get around it.

I know other methods of making requests but I wanted to try something else out and I know a work around for this but its a lot of manual labour and I would prefer to find out the cause of the error

**Code:**

```
class Request(scrapy.Request):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        process = CrawlerProcess({})
        process.crawl(self._Request, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        process.start()
        self.response: scrapy.Request = self._Request.response

    class _Request(scrapy.Spider):
        response = scrapy.Request
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.args = args
            self.kwargs = kwargs

        def start_requests(self):
            # putting the '*' in the args/kwargs of the print statement causes the same error
            print(self.args, self.kwargs)
            self.response = scrapy.Request(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            yield self.response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Request('https://scrapy.org/')
```

**Output:**

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

```
2019-12-26 16:28:24 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.8.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2019-12-26 16:28:24 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0i  14 Aug 2018), cryptography 2.3.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2019-12-26 16:28:24 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {}
2019-12-26 16:28:24 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: aaba020161f1f11b
2019-12-26 16:28:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-12-26 16:28:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-12-26 16:28:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-12-26 16:28:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-12-26 16:28:24 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-12-26 16:28:24 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-12-26 16:28:24 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
() {'args': ('https://scrapy.org/',), 'kwargs': {}}
2019-12-26 16:28:24 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "F:/Python/Projects/UserAgentListUpdater/UserAgentListUpdater/spiders/UserAgentListUpdater.py", line 66, in start_requests
    self.response = scrapy.Request(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'
2019-12-26 16:28:24 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-12-26 16:28:24 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.009006,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 27, 0, 28, 24, 586562),
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 27, 0, 28, 24, 577556)}
2019-12-26 16:28:24 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `crawl` the same way:

```
process.crawl(self._Request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `**kwargs`?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Yes, typo. Thanks

Comment: That worked but now im getting another error

raise NotImplementedError('{}.parse callback is not defined'.format(self.__class__.__name__))

NotImplementedError: _Request.parse callback is not defined

Comment: @SleepyCatGuy please do not ask new questions in comments. Open a new question instead.

Comment: @SleepyCatGuy You need to create a `parse` method for `_Request`. But Hubert Grzeskowiak is right. It's better to ask new questions when you have a different problem